# Clicking twice to see the value - UseState - UseEffect React using Function Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I'm having a newbie problem, I really read all the documentations about it, and have seen all the stackoverflow about this issue, and I still can't get it right.

I need to get a value from a const variable, that I'm seeting without clicking twice, I tried a million things and still can't make this happen.

```
    const [GetCode,setGetCode] = useState("");
     const GetCodeMI = () =>{
    Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/GetMICode',{ }).then((response)=>{

            // console.log(response.data[0].ZZE_CODIGO);
             setGetCode(response.data);
         
        });
 }   
  const  InsertInternalMov = () => {
    GetCodeMi2().then(()=>{
        console.log(GetCode[0]);
      })
  }
```

In this scenario the first time that I click on the function the value of GetCode it's undefined the second time it shows correclty. I need to get the value the first time I click, My head it still wraping around how react works.

Comment: Setting state in React is asynchronous, just because `setGetCode` has been called, doesn't mean that `GetCode` is equal to the new value (yet)

Comment: Yes that I get it , but what is the solution for this case, how could I get the value, after call the function?

Comment: How is your function being called? It must be pretty soon after the API response to be seeing this result, it might be possible to change the component to use a `useEffect` to wait for the `GetCode` change, but that would depend on the rest of the component.

Comment: I can't use the useffect because i'm using to get the last code of the database before insert a new row

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. if you want to set value immediately, you can try to use React.useRef()
2. setGetCode is asynchronous function

Comment: It is exaclty what I'm doing in the api I upadate the state of the component but i'm still havnig to click twice to see the value :(

Comment: Thank you, I kinda change the way I was getting the information